# Proof of Ptolemy's inequality?

Tags: geometry, inequality, quadrilateral

Can anyone prove the Ptolemy inequality, which states that for any convex quadrulateral $ABCD$, the following holds:$$\overline{AB}\cdot \overline{CD}+\overline{BC}\cdot \overline{DA} \ge \overline{AC}\cdot \overline{BD}$$

I know this is a generalization of Ptolemy's theorem, whose proof I know. But I have no idea on this one, can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: Define $E$ on segment $AC$ such that $\angle DAC=\angle EBC$ then use similarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Represent the four vertices as the complex numbers $a, b, c, d$. Notice that

$$ (a-b)(c-d) + (a-d)(b-c) = (a-c)(b-d),$$

which you can simply multiply out. Then we must have that

$$\begin{align}
|(a-b)(c-d) + (a-d)(b-c)| &= |(a-c)(b-d)| = |a-c||b-d| \\
|(a-b)(c-d)| + |(a-d)(b-c)| &\geq \\
|a-b||c-d| + |a-d||b-c| & \geq
\end{align}$$

which is equivalent to your question. To pass from the first line to the second, we used the triangle inequality. To pass from the second to the third (and to get the second equality on the first line), we used that absolute values are multiplicative.

In general, many elementary geometry facts are bared easily with complex numbers, or vectors in general for higher dimensions (but being able to just multiply is pretty nice).

Comment: Hmm, nice way :) Although I not very familiar with complex numbers and its use in geometry.

Comment: @karp2345: the proof can be converted to [coordinate geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry), but complex numbers can be very useful and are worth learning about.