# Prove norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

It is given that

$$\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert =\left\lVert y-z\right\rVert = \left\lVert z-x\right\rVert   \qquad (1) $$ 
where $x,y,z \in \Bbb R^2$ and $ \left\lVert x\right\rVert=\sqrt {x_1^2+x_2^2} $.

I have prove or disprove $$ (1) \Rightarrow \left\lVert x\right\rVert \le \left\lVert y\right\rVert+\left\lVert z\right\rVert$$

How could i do this?

Comment: Are you sure that $\lVert x \rVert^2=x_1^2-x_2^2$? I think there should be a $+$ sign there.

Comment: Yes, thank you! My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from Ptolemy's inequality, which states that for any quadrilateral $ABCD$, we have
$$\overline{AB}\cdot \overline{CD}+\overline{BC}\cdot \overline{DA} \ge \overline{AC}\cdot \overline{BD}.$$
Identifying $A,B,C,D$ with $0,z,x,y$, this gives
$$\left\|z-0\right\|\left\|y-x\right\|+\left\|x-z\right\|\left\|0-y\right\|\ge
\left\|x-0\right\|\left\|y-z\right\|,
$$
and we're done! Note that [the proof of Ptolemy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798395/215011) does not require $ABCD$ to be convex.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: draw a picture of $x$,$y$,$z.$ What does hypotheses mean? Then using triangle inequalities